# Remove default TextView from new activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout

When you create new activity using IDE constructor (new->activity) - in both **Android Studio** and **Eclipse** - it creates new java file, layout file, adds activity to the manifest etc.

And every time there's a `TextView` with "Hello World" text at the layout file (if you choose "Blank Activity" pattern). Also string value "Hello World" is automatically added into strings res file.

Of course no special effort is needed to delete manually string value and `TextView` but one day it becomes really annoying.

**My question:**

If there's a way to change the new activity creation mechanism and create just empty activity layout file (only with container layout, e.g. `RelativeLayout`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

`layout.template` file should be modified.

Path is: `Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\[Activity-Type]\root\res\layout`

Answer (score 3):

you can go to your sdk path
    /sdk/platforms/[android-version]/templates
and modify the template files

Answer (score 1):

Go to your SDK Path. In my case

`sdk\platforms\android-[version]\templates`

And open `layout.template` in any editor like Notepad++

Delete `Textview` widget from this `layout.template` file.